# Autoit PixelSearch inside off the screen window

Tags: search, pixel, autoit

I have a GUI off the screen and I need to do some Pixel/Image searches and clicks inside it. I think a solution is capturing the window and then do the searches on that image, but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>


Global $msg

; Create a simple GUI
GUICreate("GUI", 400, 300, (@DesktopWidth - 640) / 2, (@DesktopHeight - 580)    / 2, BitOR($WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, $WS_CLIPCHILDREN))
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)    ;Show GUI

$hwnd = WinGetHandle("GUI")
WinMove($hwnd, "", 2000, 2000)

; Waiting for user to close the window
While 1
$msg = GUIGetMsg()
Select
Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
ExitLoop
EndSelect
WEnd

GUIDelete()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answer! I need to detect some pixels, get their coordinates and then send clicks with ControlClick.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. The window is off the screen, which means that functions like PixelSearch/PixelGetColor/MouseClick won't work.

Comment: Why is it off the screen? Can't you move it in for the search and click, them move it back?